# Message Box Dialog at Exit using Tkinter in Python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, messagebox

I want to show a message box dialog when pressing the "X" button to close the GUI. I want to ask the user if he's sure he wants to exit the program with a Yes/No choice. I'm getting an error when I press "Yes" in the dialog and the GUI closes if I press "NO".  [This is the full code](https://github.com/georgeselkassouf/Beam-Designer/blob/main/beamdesigner.py)

This is the error I'm getting:

self.tk.call('destroy', self._w)

_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "destroy" command: application has been destroyed

This is what I've done so far:

```py
import atexit

def deleteme():
     result = messagebox.askquestion("Exit", "Are You Sure You Want to Exit?")
     if result == "yes":
        root.destroy()
     else:
        return None

atexit.register(deleteme)
```

Comment: What us the error you are getting? Can you please give us the full traceback. If I had to guess, it would be that root isn't defined.

Comment: Please post the entire code and error code.

Comment: I posted the full code and the error I'm getting, Thanks!

Comment: Basically it is telling you that that window is already closed. You can't close a closed window. A piece of your code destroys the window before that function is called.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.messagebox.html#tkinter.messagebox.askquestion Ask a question. By default shows buttons YES and NO. Returns the symbolic name of the selected button. so 'if result == "yes" if result == "yes" : ' --> 'if result  :  '

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `protocol` method to bind the window deletion with a function.

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

def on_close():
    response=messagebox.askyesno('Exit','Are you sure you want to exit?')
    if response:
        root.destroy()

root=Tk()
root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW',on_close)

root.mainloop()
```

**UPDATE**

According to the docs of [`atexit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/atexit.html) module

> Functions thus registered are automatically executed upon normal interpreter termination.

The function registered was called after the `mainloop` was destroyed (since nothing proceeds, it marks the end of program). The GUI element that the function tries to destroy doesn't exist anymore, as also stated by the error.

This module is not meant for the use case you trying to achieve, it's usually used for "cleanup" functions that are supposed to perform a task after the program terminates.

The callback registered via the `WM_DELETE_WINDOW` protocol gives you the control over what happens when the window is instructed to close.

Comment: Next time please explain why OP's approach didn't work. Still +1 for correct answer

Comment: @TheLizzard Oops sorry, I completely forgot, you seem to have done that, thanks. I have updated my answer with an explanation for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to @AST's answer:

You are trying to use the `atexit` library to block closing the tkinter window when the program tries to exit. The problem is that the `atexit` library calls your function after the window is destroyed. I don't even think that you can block your program exiting using the `atexit`. That is why @AST suggested using `root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_close)` which runs when the tkinter window is trying to close (works only when the user presses the "X" button).